# Predict data outside existing data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Iv'e made a basic prediction to learn this complicated area, the prediction works but only as long as i already have data.

The result i want is to predict data further than my existing data to predict what hasn't been yet.
So like i said i'm new and if someone can show me how or tell me what i dont understand good enough in the code to do this i would be grateful.

heres the code:

```
from cProfile import label
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20,10

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout, Dense

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

df = pd.read_csv('./Data/market-price-3y.csv')

# Use only one column
df = df[['Date', 'Close']]

# Change type of date from object to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# Set Date as index
df.index = df['Date']

print(df.head())

# Show the data as a graph
# plt.plot(df['Close'], label='Close Price History', color='red')
# plt.show()

df = df.sort_index(ascending=True, axis=0)

data = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0, len(df)), columns=['Date', 'Close'])

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    data['Date'][i] = df['Date'][i]
    data['Close'][i] = df['Close'][i]

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))

data.index = data.Date
data.drop('Date', axis=1, inplace=True)

# Split data into training and testing datasets
final_data = data.values
train_data = final_data[0:900,:]
valid_data = final_data[900:,:]

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))

scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(final_data)
x_train_data, y_train_data = [], []
for i in range(60, len(train_data)):
    x_train_data.append(scaled_data[i-60:i,0])
    y_train_data.append(scaled_data[i,0])

x_train_data = np.asarray(x_train_data)
y_train_data = np.asarray(y_train_data)
x_train_data = np.reshape(x_train_data, (x_train_data.shape[0], x_train_data.shape[1],1))

# Create the LSTM Model
lstm_model = Sequential()
lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(np.shape(x_train_data)[1], 1)))
lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=50))
lstm_model.add(Dense(1))

model_data = data[len(data) - len(valid_data)-60:].values
model_data = model_data.reshape(-1,1)
model_data = scaler.transform(model_data)

# Train and test the data
lstm_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
lstm_model.fit(x_train_data, y_train_data, epochs=1, batch_size=1, verbose=2)

# Test Data
X_test = []
for i in range(60, model_data.shape[0]):
    X_test.append(model_data[i-60:i,0])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))

# Result
predicted_price = lstm_model.predict(X_test)
predicted_price = scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_price)

train_data = data[:900]
valid_data = data[900:]
valid_data['Predictions'] = predicted_price
plt.plot(train_data['Close'])
plt.plot(valid_data[['Close', 'Predictions']])

plt.show()
```

[![Matplotlib output][1]][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j0Yf.png

So i want the prediction to keep going for lets say 15more points instead of ending when the test data ends.

Answer (score 0):

here you can increase the data length at this code phase:

```
# Test Data
X_test = []
for i in range(60, model_data.shape[0]):
    X_test.append(model_data[i-60:i,0])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
```

here instead of 60, you can give 60+15.
or you can create a new test dataset like similar to the above coding it depends on your data set. :)

Comment: Yes but the problem is that the data ends so the prediction doesn't have more dates in the Date column and therefore the index is out of bounds if i increase 60 here without increasing the data by the same amount (I want to predict points after the last date in the data, otherwise i already have the data).
And if i increase the data with the same amount the prediction just follows that data so is it even predicting anything?

Comment: so, you have to collect data points, or can create random data or you can reduce the training dataset. actually, the ratio of test and training you given is 50-50, but the standard ratio is 80:20. So, best is to reduce the training dataset.

Comment: or u can fill dates with zero using fill(), method

Comment: The problem is that the prediction  just follows the data set, so if I add dummy rows in data with next date and 0 as value the prediction just follows straight down aswell so that’s why I’m questioning the prediction